# Select records from date and ignore time portion not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, activerecord, time

I have a weird situation. I have created a calendar with codeigniter using the built in calendar class. Everything works as far as grabbing events and putting them on the calendar, so I know selecting dates works... but now i'm trying to select records that fall on a specific date, such as 2014-03-28, but no matter what query I use it is not pulling records from that day. I have a table and start_date is the date i'm trying to pull by, its set as dateTime. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, here's what I've tried (start_date being fed to the function is equal to Y-m-d. like 2014-03-28):

```
function get_list_events($start_date) {

    $start_date_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date.' 00:00:00'));
    $start_date_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date.' 23:59:59'));

    $this->db->where("start_date BETWEEN '$start_date_start%' AND '$start_date_end%'", NULL, FALSE);
    $query = $this->db->get('events');

    $data = array();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = array(
        'id' => $row->id,
        'title' => $row->title,
        'description' => $row->description,
        'cost' => $row->cost,
        'image' => $row->image,
        'start_date' => $row->start_date,
        'end_date' => $row->end_date,
        'venue' => $row->venue,
        'venue_address' => $row->venue_address,
        'venue_city' => $row->venue_city,
        'venue_state' => $row->venue_state,
        'venue_zipcode' => $row->venue_zipcode,
        'contact_name' => $row->contact_name,
        'contact_email' => $row->contact_email,
        'contact_phone' => $row->contact_phone,
        'contact_website' => $row->contact_website,
        'create_date' => $row->create_date,
        'active' => $row->active,
    );
    }
    return $data;

}
```

Also tried the most obvious way:

```
function get_list_events($start_date) {

    $start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date));

    $this->db->where('active', 1);
    $this->db->where('start_date', $start_date);
    $this->db->order_by('start_date', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get('events');

    $data = array();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = array(
        'id' => $row->id,
        'title' => $row->title,
        'description' => $row->description,
        'cost' => $row->cost,
        'image' => $row->image,
        'start_date' => $row->start_date,
        'end_date' => $row->end_date,
        'venue' => $row->venue,
        'venue_address' => $row->venue_address,
        'venue_city' => $row->venue_city,
        'venue_state' => $row->venue_state,
        'venue_zipcode' => $row->venue_zipcode,
        'contact_name' => $row->contact_name,
        'contact_email' => $row->contact_email,
        'contact_phone' => $row->contact_phone,
        'contact_website' => $row->contact_website,
        'create_date' => $row->create_date,
        'active' => $row->active,
    );
    }
    return $data;

}
```

And finally I tried this:

```
function get_list_events($start_date) {

    $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start_date.' 00:00:00'));
    $start_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start_date.' 23:59:59'));

    $this->db->where('active', 1);
    $this->db->where('start_date >=', $start_date);
    $this->db->where('start_date <=', $start_time);
    $this->db->order_by('start_date', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get('events');

    $data = array();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = array(
        'id' => $row->id,
        'title' => $row->title,
        'description' => $row->description,
        'cost' => $row->cost,
        'image' => $row->image,
        'start_date' => $row->start_date,
        'end_date' => $row->end_date,
        'venue' => $row->venue,
        'venue_address' => $row->venue_address,
        'venue_city' => $row->venue_city,
        'venue_state' => $row->venue_state,
        'venue_zipcode' => $row->venue_zipcode,
        'contact_name' => $row->contact_name,
        'contact_email' => $row->contact_email,
        'contact_phone' => $row->contact_phone,
        'contact_website' => $row->contact_website,
        'create_date' => $row->create_date,
        'active' => $row->active,
    );
    }
    return $data;

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check my answer, I think your queries may be wrong

Comment: The records that I am pulling all have active == 1. So removing the where active doesn't affect the query either way. Any other ideas?

Comment: BTW, i tried all the queries removing the active part, still don't work.

Comment: could you post the queries you get using last_query() (Check answer)?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you use

```
// ... Code above ...
$query = $this->db->get('events');
echo $this->db->last_query();
die();
```

And get the query you're throwing against the DDBB. With that, you'll be able of throw the query with your MySQL client and see if you really get rows with the query CI is using.

In fact, the first block of code you wrote looks well, and the others have a `$this->db->where('active', 1);` the first one haven't, so, again, check the queries, XD.